# How many multiples of X lie in the arbitrary range [Y,Z]?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to determine this without brute force?

For example

$X=3$

range $= [17,24]$

The multiples of $X$ in this range are $18$, $21$, and $24$, so $3$ multiples total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest integer $n_1$ such that $n_1X \geq Y$ is $n_1=\lceil Y/X \rceil$, and the largest integer $n_2$ such that $n_2X \leq Z$ is $n_2 = \lfloor Z/X\rfloor$.  The number of integers between $n_1$ and $n_2$ inclusive is $\max\{n_2 - n_1 + 1,0\}$, so putting that together, we get
$$\max\{\lfloor Z/X\rfloor - \lceil Y/X \rceil + 1, 0\}.$$

In your example, $X=3$, $Y=17$, and $Z=24$, so we have
$$\max\{\lfloor 24/3\rfloor - \lceil 17/3 \rceil + 1, 0\} = \max\{8-6+1,0\} = 3$$ multiples of $3$ between $17$ and $24$.

Comment: What do you do if Z/X and/or Y/X don't divide cleanly?

Comment: That's why we use the floor $\lfloor\ \rfloor$ and ceiling $\lceil\ \rceil$ functions: if $Z/X$ (or $Y/X$) isn't an integer, we round down (or up) to the nearest.

Comment: Do you have an example of where the equation would be negative? Is max necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this similar to $\lfloor (Z  - Y) / 3\rfloor$

http://maths-on-line.blogspot.in/

Comment: It is close, but you could be off by 1.  Consider $Y=1,Z=10$, for example.  Because the interval is closed, $\lfloor (Z  - Y +1) / 3\rfloor$ is better, but still not always right.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to find out the number of multiples of **X** in the range **[Y,Z]** is:
**($\lfloor$Z/X$\rfloor$ - $\lfloor$(Y-1)/X$\rfloor$)**

The **(Y-1)** is for the case where **Y** is divisible by **X**

In your example, the answer would be computed as: **($\lfloor$24/3$\rfloor$ - $\lfloor$(17-1)/3$\rfloor$) = 8 -$\lfloor$5.666...$\rfloor$ = 3**

Answer (score 0):

find the smallest $Y1$ such that $Y1 \% X == 0$ and $Y1 >= Y$. similarly, find the greatest $Z1$ such that $Z1 \% X == 0$ and $Z1 <= Z$.

Once you have $Y1$ and $Z1$ with you, it's easy:

The number of divisors of $X$ in range $[Y, Z]$ is same as in range $[Y1, Z1]$ which is $((Z1 - Y1) / X) + 1$.

Running this logic on your example:
$X = 3, Y = 17, Z = 24 => Y1 = 18, Z1 = 24 => (Z1 - Y1) = 6$

hence, the number of divisors of $3$ in range $[17, 24]$ are $(6 / 3) + 1 = 3$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: thanks, this was helpful :)