# Number of multiples of a rational number in a range

Tags: number-theory

I have an rational number $a$. I want the count of the number of integer multiples of $a$ between (and including) the values of $x$ and $y$ where $ x, y  \in \mathbb{Q}$. I know brute force ways for evaluating this but I don't want to use brute force.

I have looked at:
http://gmatclub.com/forum/determining-the-number-of-multiples-in-a-range-108603.html
and
[How many multiples of X lie in the arbitrary range [Y,Z]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211445/how-many-multiples-of-x-lie-in-the-arbitrary-range-y-z). However, both of these regard integers rather than rationals. I don't know enough of number theory to know whether the same applies to rationas.

To give further "implementation" detail, I'm trying to calculate the best "human readable" values to use for ticks in a charting library in Java that I'm writing. The values for a multiple  are `doubles` and so are rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a > 0$, and "between" means "strictly between", note that 
$x < m a < y$ if and only if $x/a < m < y/a$, and that is equivalent to
$ \lfloor x/a \rfloor + 1 \le m \le \lceil y/a \rceil - 1$, so the number
of such multiples is $$\left\lceil \frac{y}{a} \right\rceil - \left\lfloor
\frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor - 1 $$

EDIT: If "between" includes the endpoints, the condition becomes 
$\lceil x/a \rceil  \le m \le \lfloor y/a \rfloor$, and the number is

$$\left\lfloor \frac{y}{a} \right\rfloor - \left\lceil
\frac{x}{a} \right\rceil + 1 $$

Comment: I was incorrect with between and meant between and including. I shall edit my question to make that more specific.